# Periodically completely lose access to a file (cannot take ownership) in Win 2k8 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ntfs, .net, access-control-list

Running Win 2k8 R2 SP1 64 bit as a web server box with IIS 7/.NET 4.

Periodically, I completely lose access to the membership database in one of my sites (ASPNETDB) which causes a "Network Service cannot access Membership DB..." error on the site and makes the whole thing go down!  Obviously not good.

Here's what I've already tried (with an Administrator account):

- GUI tools to take ownership of that file, and of folder above it with propogation
- Command line tools from an elevated command prompt: takeown, subinacl, icacl
- Checked with Process Explorer and found **no** handles to the file

If I reboot the whole server the problem just goes away, but that is obviously not an efficient long term solution.  Any other ideas on what/how to troubleshoot?

Comment: And the file is there w/ the expected permissions after the reboot? You're not taking any steps after the reboot to resolve the issue-- it "just works"?

Comment: Yes.  There and functioning normally post reboot.

Comment: Same problem here also .. had 4 pdf files that i suddenly couldn't access/change permissions on or take ownership of as Domain Admin. Wft is happening? This is on a Clean installed server W2008 R2 Sp1 Virtualized on Hyper-V. After i rebooted the server everything was ok again. This has happened on other customers servers also. Different AV programs, backup software etc. Only thing common are W2008 R2 and SP1 ..

Comment: I've occasionally seen similar problems on Windows 7 'Ultimate', 64 bit, with all current updates applied (15 Sep, 2013).
I moved a folder, and was thereafter denied access to it, despite being able to access all the other folders at the same level. Rebooting would have been a major inconvenience, so I copied everything else to a new folder, recreated my errant files, and copied them (not moved) to the new destination. Then I could access them. It's absurd. My logon is an Administrator, but nothing I tried could restore my rights to my own files.